# Randomly and efficiently filling space with shapes

Tags: algorithm

What is the most efficient way to randomly fill a space with as many non-overlapping  shapes?  In my specific case, I'm filling a circle with circles.  I'm randomly placing circles until either a certain percentage of the outer circle is filled OR a certain number of placements have failed (i.e. were placed in a position that overlapped an existing circle).  This is pretty slow, and often leaves empty spaces unless I allow a huge number of failures.

So, is there some other type of filling algorithm I can use to quickly fill as much space as possible, but still look random?

Comment: Random is a difficult word to use correctly. Do you simply want it to look disorderly? Also are the sizes of the circles you're placing down all the same?

Comment: Disorderly would be a good description of what I want.  This is the initial pass in a terrain generation algorithm in a game, where each circle becomes a distinct terrain feature.  I simply want to ensure an irregular layout (i.e. not a grid).

Comment: The circles can be of varying sizes.  But I wouldn't mind hearing about algorithms which require homogenous shapes.

Comment: Is this related to the maximum packing density of circles? I believe that random and efficient packing are opposite design goals for this problem. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirclePacking.html

Comment: @Brian Stinar: Yeah I see what you mean.  Maximum packing by definition cannot have any randomness.  I want something fairly close to maximum packing, but with enough variation to look natural (something like what tskuzzy suggests).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Issue you are running into

You are running into the [Coupon collector's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem) because you are using a technique of [Rejection sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling).

You are also making strong assumptions about what a "random filling" is. Your algorithm will leave large gaps between circles; is this what you mean by "random"? Nevertheless it is a perfectly valid definition, and I approve of it.

---

### Solution

To adapt your current "random filling" to avoid the rejection sampling coupon-collector's issue, merely divide the space you are filling into a grid. For example if your circles are of radius 1, divide the larger circle into a grid of 1/sqrt(2)-width blocks. When it becomes "impossible" to fill a gridbox, ignore that gridbox when you pick new points. Problem solved!

---

### Possible dangers

You have to be careful how you code this however! Possible dangers:

- If you do something like `if (random point in invalid grid){ generateAnotherPoint() }` then you ignore the benefit / core idea of this optimization.
- If you do something like `pickARandomValidGridbox()` then you will slightly reduce the probability of making circles near the edge of the larger circle (though this may be fine if you're doing this for a graphics art project and not for a scientific or mathematical project); however if you make the grid size 1/sqrt(2) times the radius of the circle, you will not run into this problem because it will be impossible to draw blocks at the edge of the large circle, and thus you can ignore all gridboxes at the edge.

---

### Implementation

Thus the generalization of your method to avoid the coupon-collector's problem is as follows:

```
Inputs: large circle coordinates/radius(R), small circle radius(r)
Output: set of coordinates of all the small circles
Algorithm:
  divide your LargeCircle into a grid of r/sqrt(2)

  ValidBoxes = {set of all gridboxes that lie entirely within LargeCircle}

  SmallCircles = {empty set}

  until ValidBoxes is empty:
    pick a random gridbox Box from ValidBoxes
    pick a random point inside Box to be center of small circle C

    check neighboring gridboxes for other circles which may overlap*
    if there is no overlap:
      add C to SmallCircles
      remove the box from ValidBoxes  # possible because grid is small
    else if there is an overlap:
      increase the Box.failcount
      if Box.failcount > MAX_PERGRIDBOX_FAIL_COUNT:
        remove the box from ValidBoxes

  return SmallCircles
```

(*) This step is also an important optimization, which I can only assume you do not already have. Without it, your doesThisCircleOverlapAnother(...) function is incredibly inefficient at `O(N)` per query, which will make filling in circles nearly impossible for large ratios `R>>r`.

This is the exact generalization of your algorithm to avoid the slowness, while still retaining the elegant randomness of it.

---

### Generalization to larger irregular features

**edit:** Since you've commented that this is for a game and you are interested in irregular shapes, you can generalize this as follows. For any small irregular shape, enclose it in a circle that represent how far you want it to be from things. Your grid can be the size of the smallest terrain feature. Larger features can encompass 1x2 or 2x2 or 3x2 or 3x3 etc. contiguous blocks. Note that many games with features that span large distances (mountains) and small distances (torches) often require grids which are recursively split (i.e. some blocks are split into further 2x2 or 2x2x2 subblocks), generating a tree structure. This structure with extensive bookkeeping will allow you to randomly place the contiguous blocks, however it requires a lot of coding. What you can do however is use the circle-grid algorithm to place the larger features first (when there's lot of space to work with on the map and you can just check adjacent gridboxes for a collection without running into the coupon-collector's problem), then place the smaller features. If you can place your features in this order, this requires almost no extra coding besides checking neighboring gridboxes for collisions when you place a 1x2/3x3/etc. group.

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but what is the significance of r/sqrt(2) as the grid width? Why is this the best choice?

Answer (score 9):

One way to do this that produces interesting looking results is

```
create an empty NxM grid
create an empty has-open-neighbors set
for i = 1 to NumberOfRegions
   pick a random point in the grid
   assign that grid point a (terrain) type
   add the point to the has-open-neighbors set
while has-open-neighbors is not empty
   foreach point in has-open-neighbors
      get neighbor-points as the immediate neighbors of point 
          that don't have an assigned terrain type in the grid
      if none
         remove point from has-open-neighbors
      else
         pick a random neighbor-point from neighbor-points
         assign its grid location the same (terrain) type as point
         add neighbor-point to the has-open-neighbors set
```

When done, has-open-neighbors will be empty and the grid will have been populated with at most NumberOfRegions regions (some regions with the same terrain type may be adjacent and so will combine to form a single region).

Sample output using this algorithm with 30 points, 14 terrain types, and a 200x200 pixel world:

[image]

Edit: tried to clarify the algorithm.

Comment: I'm not quite following your pseudo-code.  Is the initial for loop populating the "has-open-neighbors" list?  If not, what is the while loop doing?

Comment: The for loop creates the initial population, the while loop updates the population while expanding the terrains until there are no unassigned points in the grid.  See https://gist.github.com/1067469 for a C# implementation.  Takes about 8 seconds (on my box) to populate a 1000x1000 grid with 300 regions using 14 terrain types.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a 2-step process:

1. Choose a bunch of n points randomly -- these will become the centres of the circles.
2. Determine the radii of these circles so that they do not overlap.

For step 2, for each circle centre you need to know the distance to its nearest neighbour.  (This can be computed for all points in O(n^2) time using brute force, although it may be that faster algorithms exist for points in the plane.)  Then simply divide that distance by 2 to get a safe radius.  (You can also shrink it further, either by a fixed amount or by an amount proportional to the radius, to ensure that no circles will be touching.)

To see that this works, consider any point p and its nearest neighbour q, which is some distance d from p.  If p is also q's nearest neighbour, then both points will get circles with radius d/2, which will therefore be touching; OTOH, if q has a different nearest neighbour, it must be at distance d' < d, so the circle centred at q will be even smaller.  So either way, the 2 circles will not overlap.

Answer (score 1):

My idea would be to start out with a compact grid layout. Then take each circle and perturb it in some random direction. The distance in which you perturb it can also be chosen at random (just make sure that the distance doesn't make it overlap another circle).

This is just an idea and I'm sure there are a number of ways you could modify it and improve upon it.